# Trouble With SQL Query in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

Hello I'm getting an error: near "join": syntax error. Is there an obvious issue with this that I'm not picking up on? I've changed names in the query but I've gone over and checked for spelling errors already.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql

path1 = r'C:\file.xlsx'
path2 = r'C:\file2.xlsx'
tenants = pd.read_excel(path1, sheet_name='1')
buildings = pd.read_excel(path2)

db = sql.connect('temp.db')

tenants.to_sql('tenantsdb', db)
buildings.to_sql('buildingsdb', db)

Query = pd.read_sql("select t.*, b.distance from tenantsdb t where city = 'city' join buildingsdb b on t.Address = b.Street_Address;", db)

db.close()
```

Comment: `JOIN` goes before `WHERE`.

Comment: Also, if `city` column exists in both tables you probably want `t.city='city'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, the order of clauses is `SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`. You have `JOIN` in the wrong place.

```
Query = pd.read_sql("""
    select t.*, b.distance 
    from tenantsdb t 
    join buildingsdb b on t.Address = b.Street_Address 
    where city = 'city';""", db)
```

Comment: While its always disappointing to find its a simple mistake its also nice when its a simple mistake. Thank you!